# Moodle does not react to unenrollment

Tags: moodle

I'm using the [WebHooks](https://moodle.org/plugins/local_webhooks) Module to react on the event `\core\event\course_module_completion_updated`. The event is forwarded to an external API endpoint where I do some validation. If the user completed every Module and did some additional work, the user is unenrolled using the WebService-API-Function `enrol_manual_unenrol_users`. This works fine so far but there is one problem. The Moodle website does not react to the unenrollment. As long as the user stays on the website without reloading he can still mark modules as completed or take that back. Only after reloading the user is restricted to do that.

Why are the endpoints of Moodle not secured for this situation? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm - can the user _actually_ mark activities as complete/incomplete or is it just that the webpage makes it look like they can (but the actual update is rejected on the server side)?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it. The user is able to take the completion back. The TimeStamp changed from 1690984033 to 1690984107 and the completion state from 1 to 0